# Centralized control with Git on VSTS

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

We use TFVC on our VSTS (formerly VSO) repository. Because we like having centralized control over our code.

We, now, want to add Visual Studio Code to the mix in our team and looks like VS Code only supports Git.

Can we use Git in our VSTS repository and still maintain centralized control?

At this point, the only reason for using Git would be VS Code -- unless there's another good reason.

Comment: You can have centralized "workflows" set up around git (including using central repo), if that's what you are worried about.

Comment: I'd say that developers are flocking to git because it is the best thing out there (even Microsoft supporting it says a ton). But I think that's out of the scope of your question.

Comment: I recognize that Git is the new and popular way. Is there anything special we need to do to set up Git so that workflow is centralized? We just use TFVC out of the box without modifying anything and we're pretty happy with it. I'm wondering if using Git in a centralized way will require some "substantial" or "unsubstantial" effort on our part.

Comment: Don't know TFVC so can't really name the differences. However I've used centralized tools and git is a _big leap_ if you are used to thinking in "centralized terms". I guess you can read all the material that's out there that compares svn with git and you will probably be able to get the "overall" differences. It does require some "working with it" in order to learn the basics (stash, cherry-picking, rebasing... just to name the most basic ones). Once you get used to it, you will be wondering how you were able to live so long without it (that's from my personal experience).

Comment: Coming back to the question about "do we need anything special to work with git in a centralized fashion"? Not really. Just set up a central repo (probably a bare one) on one of your servers that people can get access to whenever they want to "sync" (fetch/push). There's plenty of transports that git can use (ssh, https, etc), but those are _details_, say.

Comment: Great! I'll play with it. Thank you. If you make your comment an answer, I can mark it as an answer so that you get credit for your responses :-)

Comment: No worries. Just add the points for the comments you liked. Let us know if you have other questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know TFVC at all, but there are many reasons to use Git instead which can simply be summarized by "Git is the best thing that happened to VCS and there is virtually nothing that you cannot do with it".

This also includes using it in a centralized workflow. If you want a centralized workflow, just set up a central bare repository to which every developer is pushing to and fetching from and you are basically done with your centralized workflow setup.

Comment: You can't do file and folder-level security restrictions in Git.

Comment: @DanielMann of course you can. Just make a `pre-receive` hook that does whatever check you want or use a Git hosting solution that supports it out-of-the box. I did a similar thing with a `pre-receive` hook myself already, where you can have a checked in file that controls access to branches if present in the branch or by default in `master`. But this could easily be done on folder or file level too without any problem.

Comment: I'm talking about scenarios where there are files located in source control that some people should not even be able to view. It's trivial to set security restrictions on individual files or folders in TFVC, but that's not the case in Git.

Comment: Well, yeah, that might not be possible easily. But for that you can make a submodule and control access to the submodule if you need it. But honestly I think if you need it, you have a broken concept or the wrong tool. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

VS Code now supports TFVC. [Announcement back in April](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/04/12/official-release-of-tfvc-support-for-visual-studio-code/).

I love Git and think it's great, but there are scenarios where centralized VC still wins.

- File- and folder-level security is essentially not possible under Git. You can try pre-receive hooks and submodules, but these bring their own complications and don't completely cover the space that centralized VC can cover.
- Large binaries. While [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) makes this better, it's an add-on and the seams sometimes show.
- Huge number of files in your working directory. [GVFS](https://github.com/Microsoft/gvfs) solves this, but again, it's an add-on. Most centralized VCs don't have an issue with working directory size. Since "work on file" tends to be an explicit operation, they don't have to grovel the filesystem on checkin.